# ValueError when training the CNN using colab

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am getting following error when I'm trying to train the CNN.

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-1-8308471ad202> in <cell line: 89>()
         87 tf.data.experimental.enable_debug_mode()
         88 # Train the model
    ---> 89 model.fit(
         90     train_generator,
         91     steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples // batch_size,
    
    1 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
       1695                 logs = tf_utils.sync_to_numpy_or_python_type(logs)
       1696                 if logs is None:
    -> 1697                     raise ValueError(
       1698                         "Unexpected result of `train_function` "
       1699                         "(Empty logs). Please use "
    
    ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.
```

I have stored my images in google drive and use separate.csv files for introduces images with label names.And it is runining fine untile the model compilation. Then it occures the above error.BTW I'm pretty new to this method.My code is like the following code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import pandas as pd
import os

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
%cd /content/gdrive/My Drive/

# Set the paths to your dataset directories
train_dir = './train'
test_dir = './test'

test_items = os.listdir(test_dir)
print("Items in test_dir:")
for item in test_items:
    print(item)

# Load the data into a dataframe
train_df = pd.read_csv('./train.csv')
test_df = pd.read_csv('./test.csv')

# Define image parameters
img_width, img_height = 150, 150
input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)  # Adjust for grayscale images

# Define hyperparameters
batch_size = 32
epochs = 10
learning_rate = 0.001

# Create data generators with data augmentation for training and validation
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=10,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    shear_range=0.1,
    zoom_range=0.1,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest'
)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    train_df,
    x_col='filename',
    y_col='fat_percentage',
    directory=train_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='raw'
)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    test_df,
    x_col='filename',
    y_col='fat_percentage',
    directory=test_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='raw'
)

# Define the CNN architecture
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)  # No activation function for regression task
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(
    loss='mse',
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),
    metrics=['mae'],
)

tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
tf.data.experimental.enable_debug_mode()
# Train the model
model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs
)

# Evaluate the model on the test set
test_loss, test_mae = model.evaluate(test_generator, verbose=2)
print(f'Test Loss: {test_loss:.4f}')
print(f'Test MAE: {test_mae:.4f}')
```

What's causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an image classification problem and not a regression task. If the images are greyscale, then the input_shape must be input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 1). Here 1 is the channel number. If the images are color images(RGB) then the number of channels would be 3.

Share the dataset, it will be helpful in understanding the problem

Comment: I am trying train custom dataset. The data was collected by me. It is just basically  labeled body images with  fat percentage. I don't whether it will work or not.

Comment: @Axen_Rangs Are the labels part of your training data set? I don't see that in your code example in the question.

Comment: I was able to provide labels and resolve this issue. Now I am facing a problem with accuracy.